# How can I acquire a certain "random range" in a higher frequency?

Tags: random, lua, frequency

My question is basically, *"how can I obtain certain random values within a specific range more than random values outside the range?"*

Allow me to demonstrate what I mean:

> If I were to, on a good amount of trials, start picking a variety of
> random numbers from *1-10*, I should be seeing more numbers in the *7-10*
> range than in the *1-6* range.

I tried a couple of ways, but I am not getting desirable results.

## First Function:

```
function getAverage(i)
    math.randomseed(os.time())  
    local sum = 0;
    for j = 1,i do
        sum = sum + (1-math.random()^3)*10
    end
    print(sum/i)
end

getAverage(500)
```

I was constantly getting numbers only around 7.5, such as 7.48, and 7.52. Although this does indeed get me a number within my range, I don't want such strict consistancy.

## Second Function:

```
function getAverage(i)
    math.randomseed(os.time())  
    local sum = 0;
    for j = 1,i do
        sum = sum + (math.random() > .3 and math.random(7,10) or math.random(1,6))
    end
    print(sum/i)
end

getAverage(500)
```

This function didn't work as I wanted it to either. I primarily getting numbers such as *6.8* and *7.2* but nothing even close to *8*.

## Third Function:

```
function getAverage(i)
    math.randomseed(os.time())  
    local sum = 0;
    for j = 1,i do
        sum = sum + (((math.random(10) * 2)/1.2)^1.05) - math.random(1,3)
    end
    print(sum/i)
end

getAverage(500)
```

This function was giving me slightly more favorable results, with the function consistently returning *8*, but that is the issue - `consistency`.

**What type of paradigms or practical solutions can I use to generate more random numbers within a specific range over another range?**

*I have labeled this as Lua, but a solution in any language that is understandable is acceptable.*

Comment: Just choose a probability density function you like, calculate inverse of cumulative distribution function and generate random values according to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **I don't want such strict consistancy.**

What does that mean?

If you average a very large number of values in a given range from any RNG, you should *expect* that to produce the same number. That means each of the numbers in the range was equally likely to appear.

> This function didn't work as I wanted it to either. I primarily getting numbers such as 6.8 and 7.2 but nothing even close to 8.

You have to clarify what "didn't work" means. Why would you expect it to give you 8? You can see it won't just by looking at the formula you used.

For instance, if you'd used `math.random(1,10)`, assuming all numbers in the range have an equal chance of appearing, you should expect the average to be 5.5, dead in the middle of 1 and 10 (because (1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10)/10 = 5.5).

You used `math.random() > .3 and math.random(7,10) or math.random(1,6)` which is saying 70% of the time to give 7, 8, 9, or 10 (average = 8.5) and 30% of the time to give you 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, or 6 (average = 3.5). That should give you an overall average of 7 (because 3.5 * .3 + 8.5 * .7 = 7). If you bump up your sample size, that's exactly what you'll see. You're seeing values on either size because you sample size is so small (try bumping it up to 100000).

Comment: Cheers for the explanation. I understood that what I'm doing isn't exactly right, but that's why I need assistance. How can I get varying numbers from 7-10 upon getting the average?

Comment: Stop taking the average. If what you want is "a random number from 1-10, with 70% more numbers in the 7-10 range than in the 1-6 range" then you just need `math.random() > .3 and math.random(7,10) or math.random(1,6)`. That's it. Don't add it to a sum of hundreds of other values and take an average (that should always produce roughly the same value), just take the number and use it.

Comment: I just quickly printed 10 numbers from the result of that ternary expression, and I realized you're right: taking the average made no sense because almost the same value would come out anyways. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've made skewed random values before by simply generating two random numbers in the range, and then picking the largest (or smallest). This skews the probability towards the high (or low) endpoint.

Picking the smallest of two gives you a linear probability distribution.
Picking the smallest of three gives you a parabolic distribution (more selectivity, less probability at "the other end"). For my needs, a linear distribution was fine.

Not exactly what you wanted, but maybe it's good enough.

Have fun!